# What programm is best to encrypt folders and files on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, encryption

I want to encrypt some files but can't find trusty programm to do that, and TrueCrypt is unsafe now atleast it's what the internet say.

Any advice will be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [CryFS](https://www.cryfs.org/)
- [EncFS](https://vgough.github.io/encfs/)
- [eCryptFS](http://ecryptfs.org/)

Compare: https://www.cryfs.org/comparison -- Scroll to 'Summary' section

Ubuntu package names: `cryfs`, `encfs`, `ecryptfs-utils`